# iTunes store operation failed ' is correct

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Good evening, I'm trying to upload an ios app to the apple store, but when validating, or uploading I get this error:
[error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyCyr.png)

What is it suppose to mean?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect a failure is associated with technical work on the server. I had similar warnings when downloading applications to the store. Try sending later